# Modification Yii CRUD generate (Gii) form template

Tags: php, yii

I want to change the Gii template follow my own template that I have where I found the code to change

`<div class="errorMessage">....</div>` become my own template style??

I have changed most of the gii templates style follow mine but i have not found the line to change the "div" error message on : `framework\gii\generators\crud\templates\default`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main view file for CRUD generation is in `framework\gii\generators\crud\templates\views\index.php`. The form is generated using [CCodeForm](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CCodeForm), and the error messages are generated using the $form->error() method.

You can customise these considerably by just passsing parameters to the $form->error() method as described [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#error-detail), or you can override the $form->error() method by creating your own class which extends CCodeForm, but that may have unintended results!

I'd suggest, for ease, that you pass parameters to each of the $form->error() methods that are called in the view file.

To do this, follow these steps;

1. Create a folder 'gii' in your protected folder
2. Create a folder within that called 'crud'
3. Into that folder copy the entire contents of `framework/gii/generators/crud. These files will now override the default files from gii.
4. Open `protected/gii/crud/views/index.php`
5. Find all the error fields. They look like `<?php echo $form->error($model,'controller'); ?>`
6. Add an array of html options to the error declaration, so it looks like `<?php echo $form->error($model,'controller', array('class' => 'alert alert-error')); ?>`
7. Thats it! This method has the benefit that you haven't modified the core framework files, so if you update yii your changes will not be overwritten. For more information, have a look at this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii

Comment: How to change `<div class="errorMessage">Can't be empty</div>` with my own html tag style ? ex : `<div class="alert alert-error">Can't be empty</div>`

Comment: @BerthoJoris I have expanded my answer to add further detail about overriding gii generators. Hope that helps.